# Is it possible to reload UITableView except particular rows of section?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to reload particular `section` of `UITableView` but it's not working properly means all `section`s are reloading. How to fix that issue

Code:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation({ 
  let loc = self.cartTbl.contentOffset 
  self.cartTbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sender.tag), with: .middle);
  self.cartTbl.contentOffset = loc 
})
```

here `sender.tag` means am passing section number on button click

Comment: Show some code here

Comment: UIView.performWithoutAnimation({

                let loc = self.cartTbl.contentOffset
                self.cartTbl.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sender.tag), with: .middle);
                
self.cartTbl.contentOffset = loc
            })

here sender.tag means am passing section number on button click

Comment: use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withAnimation:`

Answer (score 2):

```
let sectionIndex = 1
let set: IndexSet = [sectionIndex]
self.tableView.reloadSections(set, with: .automatic)
```

You can use reload section method of table view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `reloadSections` method for updating a specific section? With the method `reloadSections` you can reload a specific section without reloading other sections of the table.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614954-reloadsections?language=objc